# How To Change the content/value of button with jQuery with it being in its hover state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a button and would like to change the content of it when its in its hover state. I looked through alot of  the question that may already have my answer, and unfortunately  came up blank, your help is greatly appreciated. This is what i have so far

Thanks Guys

```
$("#button").hover(function(){
$(this).html("click me");
}
```

Comment: okay Thank You Figured it out  $("#button").hover(function(){
$(this).vall("click me");
}

Comment: Be aware that hover doesn't work on touch devices.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **[`hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)** handler like this

```js
$("#button").hover(function() {
  $(this).html("click me");
}, function() {
  $(this).html("click");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id=button>click</button>
```

**Update :** If you are using `input` tag then use **[`val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/)** instead of [`html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/)

```js
$("#button").hover(function() {
  $(this).val("click me");
}, function() {
  $(this).val("click");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=button id=button value=click>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#button1").hover(function() {
  $(this).val("click me");
}, function() {

  $(this).val("hi")

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="button1" type="button" value="hi">
```

Comment: be kind enough and tell me whats wrong with my answer so that can correct it.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with your answer from what I can tell. Probably serial downvoters who want their answer to rock out!

Comment: i did correct it as OP mentioned in other post he wants value to change.

Comment: You are fine buddy. I sent you a +1 as I can see your revisions